# How to calculate percentage with date

Tags: php

How can I do the percent calculation with dates since I have the following code

```
$date_today = date("Y-m-d");
$date_db = $row['date_final'];

$date1 = new DateTime($date_today);
$date2 = new DateTime($date_db);

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
$result = $diff->format("%a");
```

The result of my variable `$result` and the total days of difference of the given date1 and date2 as I do the percent with them with that result of the variable `$result`

Comment: Percentage of what?

Comment: What are you expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: You need 3 dates right? the beginning date, the today date and the final date, so you can determine what precentage today is to the end, based on the beginning date. Is that what you want?

Comment: The expected output would be the missing percent for `date1` to reach `date2`

Comment: @PedroSilva no i need 2 dates. today and final what is the date of the `db`

Comment: percentage of what, as hanky already asked.

Comment: You're always going to be 0% of the way between now and a date/time in the future. If you want to actually calculate a percentage you need to be *between* ***two*** date/times.

Comment: @diegogoncalves if you just have today and final imagine this. If the begin date was yesterday and final is tomorrow, then today is 50% right? Just to describe this I used 3 dates. If the start date was 3 days ago, then it is 75%. so today and final date is not enough to calculate as the start date will change the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some psuedo code, which may or may not help.

```
$date_start = 20160101
$date_today = 20160315 // 75 days have passed
$date_end = 20161231 // 366 days in total
```

Calculate the difference between $date_start and $date_today, which should give you 75.  I'll call that $date_so_far.

What you are missing as far as getting a percentage is the *TOTAL* number of days in the calculation.  Get that by doing a difference between $date_end and $date_start.  I'll call that $date_range.

```
$date_pct = $date_so_far / $date_range 
// should give you roughly .21, which represents that you are about 20% into your range.
```

Is that what you are seeking?

Comment: no it would look something like this. `$date = ($date2 * 100) / $result`